how to make my react-native app build with expo compatible with old version of ios
I'm building a app with expo and i want the app can be compatible  with older version iphone and android ( for exemple i want my to be  compatible with  ios 12 till ios 17.   some have idea? thanks
try documentation but no fund solution

Expo dropped support for iOS 12. But if you still need it you can use older versions. Expo 46 supports starting from iOS 12.4 and 43 supports starting from 12.0. See the examples below.
iOS 12.4 and abone:
npx create-expo-app --template blank@46

iOS 12.0 and above:
npx create-expo-app --template blank@43

